# Get the name of the module that required the current module

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to get the name of the caller module that `require`d the current module, inside the current module?

I see there is a `module.parent.filename` but this returns only the first module that needed the current module.

#### core.js

```
console.log('Caller module: ' + module.parent.filename)
```

#### module1.js

```
require('core')
```

> Caller module: [...]/module1.js

#### module2.js

```
require('core')
```

> Caller module: [...]/module1.js

I am asking this because nobody else asked specifically for the above feature (or at least that's what I concluded) and it is not clear to me if it is possible or not to obtain inside the *required* the name of *requirer* when a `require` happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module is only required once in node. The other call is just a pointer to the module that was already loaded. The only way of doing this would be to export a function in the module and call that function when loading. That would look something like this:

**core.js**

```
module.exports = function (higherModule) {
    console.log('Caller module: ' + higherModule)
}
```

**module1.js**

```
require('./core')('module1')
```

**module2.js**

```
require('./core')('module2')
```